# Перевести "Link to image on the web" при загрузке изображения со стороннего сайта

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, редактор

При вставке изображения по ссылке, появляется сообщение *"Link to image on the web":*
[image: Link to image on the web]

Предлагаю перевести:
*Ссылка на изображение*

Comment: Добавьте ответами варианты перевода. Участники проголосуют за лучший вариант.

Comment: Можно еще `указатель на изображение` :) Это конечно шутка, но я стороник варианта  `ссылка на изображение` , так как *краткость - сестра таланта.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Учитывая, что ссылки из интернета остаются таковыми, то есть изображение не закачивается на imgur, который можно с некоторой натяжкой считать внутренним ресурсом, предлагаю перевести как:

> Ссылка на внешнее изображение

Comment: Добавил в транс. Ключ `17d6b25c9a2994b4afb37f4f4d46f7c3`.

Comment: @Suvitruf утвердил

Answer (score -2):

Дословно и понятно

> Ссылка на изображение в интернете